# How to copy single image from vector of images to a temporary cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I call a function rgbTOgray and trying to copy each image in a "vector of images" (which is a vector of colored images) to a temporary cv::Mat using a for loop. And, convert it to grayscale using cvtColor. Here is the code:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> rgbTOgray(std::vector<cv::Mat>& rgb_image)
{
  cv::Mat temp_gray, temp_rgb;
  std::vector<cv::Mat> gray_image;
  std::vector<cv::Mat>::iterator itr;

  for ( itr = rgb_image.begin() ; itr < rgb_image.end() ; itr++) 
  {
    temp_rgb = *itr;
    cvtColor(temp_rgb, temp_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    gray_image.push_back(temp_gray);
  }

  return gray_image;
}
```

**EDIT:** I am returning a vector of Gray-scale images "gray_image". But this doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT_2:** OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor

Could anybody please help me out? I am new and learning all this stuff.
Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work ? Could you provide error messages or expected/actual output ?

Comment: @JBL please check EDIT_2 for error

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884660/error-in-implementing-realtime-camera-based-gpu-surf-in-opencv

Comment: @JBL is the line: " temp_rgb = *itr "  correct??

I also tried *itr.copyTo(temp_rgb) that doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that you are forgetting that `cv::Mat` is reference counted with a "copy" not really copying anything, just a pointer.
The `push_back(temp_grey)` keeps pushing the same image into your array.
You should declare `cv::Mat temp_gray` inside the loop to make sure you get fresh copies for each element.

Also, check the number of channels of your "rgb" images (`temp_rgb.channels()`). The assert basically says that they are not 3/4 channels.

Comment: how to check number of channels?

Comment: @user2151446 thanks!! No. of channels is indeed 1. Is there a way to convert single channel image to 3-channel image?

Comment: @AdiShavit thanks to u too!!  No. of channels is indeed 1. Is there a way to convert single channel image to 3-channel image? I think these are single channel rgb images....i need to convert them to gray-scale for my rest of code to work perfectly....

Comment: If the image has 1 channel only, it means it is not an RGB image (as far as I know). Are you sure those images are not already in grayscale? A way to make your function valid for gray and rgb images is to just copy the images with a single channel.

Comment: I figured out I can read the images directly as gray-scale:
**imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE))**

no need of above function now!! :D

thanks all!!!

Answer (score 4):

You are not storing in vector `gray_image` the gray images, but `cv::Mat` headers with pointers to a single block of memory data which is firstly allocated by `temp_gray`. You must clone those data not to overwrite your images:

```
gray_image.push_back(temp_gray.clone());
```

By the way, I would add `gray_image.reserve(rgb_image.size());` before your loop.

Comment: is the line:  'temp_rgb = *itr'  correct??   I also tried *itr.copyTo(temp_rgb) that doesn't work...

Comment: It is ok, but you do not actually need it. You can just write cvtColor(*itr, temp_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

Answer (score 0):

I do't know exactly why (I'm a learner too) but in my case it works only with `.clone()` when you push back the temp image just gray-convert.

Anyway, the iterator line in your code is correct.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

std::vector<cv::Mat> rgb2gray(std::vector<cv::Mat>& rgb_image)
{
  cv::Mat temp_gray;
  std::vector<cv::Mat> gray_image;
  std::vector<cv::Mat>::iterator itr;

  gray_image.reserve(rgb_image.size());
  for ( itr = rgb_image.begin() ; itr < rgb_image.end() ; itr++)
  {
    cvtColor(*itr, temp_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    gray_image.push_back(temp_gray.clone());
  }
  return gray_image;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) {
    Mat imgA, imgB;   
    imgA = imread("test1.jpg");
    imgB = imread("test2.jpg");

    vector<Mat> input;
    input.push_back(imgA);
    input.push_back(imgB);

    vector<Mat> output;
    output = rgb2gray(input);

    stringstream ss;
    for(size_t i = 0; i<input.size(); i++) {
        ss.str(""); ss << "in" << i;
        imshow( ss.str(), input[i] );

        ss.str(""); ss << "out" << i;
        imshow( ss.str(), output[i] );
    }

    while( true ) {
        char c = (char)waitKey(10);
        if( c == 27 )
            { break; }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I figured out I can read the images directly as gray-scale: imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE))

thanks!